# postgresql date diff between two date with two table and two fields

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I have one table with name tblprop and data:

```
houseid | date      |

--------+------------

 1      | 2014-10-10|
```

and another table with name tbltrans and data:

```
transno |houseid | transdate    |

--------+-------- +--------------

 1      |   1     |2014-10-20   |
```

I want a query that calculates the difference between **date** of `tblprop` and **transdate** of `tbltrans` and the result is in terms of days.

result is like this:

```
houseid | difference|

--------+------------

 1      | 10days    |
```

Thanks and more power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subtract them. As both are dates the result of the difference is the number of days.

```
select p.houseid,
       t.transdate - p.date
from tblprop p
  join tbltrans t on t.houseid = p.houseid;
```

If both were `timestamp` columns you'd get back an `interval` (rather than an integer representing days)